# Cocoapods files are missing in flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, cocoapods

I'm not an ios developer and am trying to add Firebase to my Flutter project. I followed the firebase guideline of adding an ios project. I first moved the `GoogleService-Info.plist` into `Runner/Runner` in Xcode. Thereafter I executed `$pod init` and added `pod 'Firebase Core'` into the `Podfile`. As described in the setup guide I executed `pod install` thereafter. This command already shows the following error messages:

> [!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a
>   platform for this target in your Podfile. See
>   `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
>
> [!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project
>   because your project already has a custom config set. In order for
>   CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base
>   configurations of the target `Runner` to `Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig` or include the
>   `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig` in
>   your build configuration (`Flutter/Debug.xcconfig`).
>
> [!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project
>   because your project already has a custom config set. In order for
>   CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base
>   configurations of the target `Runner` to `Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig` or include the
>   `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig`
>   in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).
>
> [!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project
>   because your project already has a custom config set. In order for
>   CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base
>   configurations of the target `Runner` to `Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the
>   `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig`
>   in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).

When I now try to run my app the `debug concol` outputs these errors:

> ```
> === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
> diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
> diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
> error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
> ```

It seems as if some files are missing even though they are inside the ios project folder.

Comment: did you solved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found out that it's not necessary to run these `pod` comments. It's only required to move the google-services file into the iOS project.

Answer (score 0):

follow the three simple step. 
flutter terminal, 
1. cd ios
2. pod init
3. pod install

after than, flutter run.